# How to convert a list of java objects to Map<String, Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, java-8, protocol-buffers, collectors

I have a list of java objects as below:

```json
[
  {
    id: "frwfhfijvfhviufhbviufg",
    country_code: "DE",
    message_key: "key1",
    translation: "This is the deutsch translation"
  },
  {
    id: "dfregregtegetgetgttegt",
    country_code: "GB",
    message_key: "key1",
    translation: "This is the uk translation"
  },
  {
    id: "frffgfbgbgbgbgbgbgbgbg",
    country_code: "DE",
    message_key: "key2",
    translation: "This is the again deutch translation"
  }
]
```

How can I convert this into a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` like below:

```json
{
  "DE": {
    "key1": "This is the deutsch translation",
    "key2": "This is the again deutch translation"
  },
  "GB": {
    "key1": "This is the uk translation"
  }
}
```

I am new to java and below is my code but the code is not correct:

```java
Map<String, Translations> distinctTranslations = customTranslationsEntities
        .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                CustomTranslationsEntity::getCountryCode,
                Collectors.toMap(
                        CustomTranslationsEntity::getMessageKey,
                        CustomTranslationsEntity::getTranslation),

                )))
```

where Translations is proto buffer message like below:

```
message Translations {
  map<string, string> translations = 1;
}
```

Here `map<string, string> translations` means map like `"key1", "This is the deutsch translation"`...like this.

Comment: Is Translations a class ?

Comment: Thanks, @Anish for the help. Yes, `Translations` is a proto buffer message which is of type map<string, string>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output should be `Map<String, Map<String,String>>`:

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>>
    distinctTranslations = customTranslationsEntities
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CustomTranslationsEntity::getCountryCode,
                                    Collectors.toMap(
                                            CustomTranslationsEntity::getMessageKey,
                                            CustomTranslationsEntity::getTranslation,
                                            (v1,v2)->v1)));
```

I added a merge function, in case there are duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how should I convert Map<String, Map<String, String>> to Map<String, Translations>. Where `Translations` is a Map<String, String>

Comment: @Deepika What do you mean by `Where Translations is a Map<String, String>`? Do you mean `Translations` extends `Map<String,String>`? Or do you mean it's a class that contains a `Map<String,String>` instance variable?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here `Translations` mean to extends Map<String,String>

Comment: @Deepika Why do you want to extend `Map<String,String>`? I don't see the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without using streams then

```
private List<MyObject> list = // Your object List
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

for(MyObject object : list){
    Map<String, String> localMap;
    localMap = map.getOrDefault(object.country_code, new HashMap<>());
    localMap.put(object.message_key, object.translation);
    if(!map.containsKey(object.country_code)){
        map.put(object.country_code, localMap);
    }
}
```